# Why does python VM have co_names instead of just using co_consts?

Tags: python, bytecode, vm-implementation

A code object generated by Python compiler contains a tuple of constants used in the instructions (named `co_consts`) and also a tuple containing names (named `co_names`).

Why having two distinct lists? Wouldn't be simpler to just use `co_consts` for names too?

Comment: Just to check, you're talking about cpython correct? Which version?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: `co_names` is used in cpython both 2 and 3 and in pypy. Not sure about other implementations because I don't use them.

Comment: I don't remember all that well, but I'm pretty sure it has something to do with pickling.

Answer (score 7):

Consider the following function.

```
def f(x):
    x += n
    return x * 4
```

Here `x` is a local name, its value can change. `4` is a constant. Its value will never change. However, it's still an object and it's better to cache them rather than create a new object each time it's needed. Finally, `n` is a global reference. The string `"n"` is stored by the function so that it can be used as a key to retrieve `n` from the function's global context.

```
>>> f.__code__.co_nlocals # just 1 (for x)
1
>>> f.__code__.co_consts
(None, 4)
>>> f.__code__.co_names
('n',)
>>> "n" in f.__globals__ and globals() is f.__globals__
True
```

The reason for keeping names and consts separate is for the purposes of introspection. The only real reason to merge the tuples would be memory efficiency, though this would only gain you one object and one pointer per function. Consider the following function.

```
def g():
    return "s" * n
```

If the tuple containing consts was merged with the tuple containing names then you (not the VM) wouldn't be able to tell which values were for accessing globals and which were constants of the function.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is like 11 months out of date but from my tinkering it seems the following is happening

To access co_names in bytecode, one uses LOAD_GLOBAL(co names index) and this pushes a reference to the desired co_names onto the stack, eg its indirect

To access co_consts in bytecode, one uses LOAD_CONST(co consts index) and this pushes the actual value stored at the desired co_consts onto the stack, eg its direct

I'm not sure it has any direct bearing at a python level, but at a bytecode level its a profound difference

Comment: Of course there is a big difference as `LOAD_CONST` loads a constant on the stack while `LOAD_GLOBAL` instead does a lookup. However the global **name** is just a Python `str` object and could have placed in the `co_consts` list instead of `co_names`. The point of my question is "why using two lists when just using the `co_const` one would have been sufficient?"... I am **not** saying that `LOAD_GLOBAL` opcode is not needed because we have `LOAD_CONST`, but just that the two could have used the same list instead of having two lists. Any opcode referring a **name** could have used `op_consts`.

Comment: I don't know the reason its designed like that but the 2 instructons push different types of data onto the stack (value vs reference)

Comment: If you did have both consts and names merged you'd still need some kind of instruction to tell the VM whether it's a reference or value, so that's 2 instructions per load, eg loadconstname, setconstnametype, and that isn't as fast as a single call, plus if you have idjuts (eg me) messing with bytecode its safer from the VM perspective