# Why attribute names are symbols and not string constants in CPython bytecode?

Tags: python, python-internals

I have hard time understanding why attributes, e.g. `attr` in

```
obj.attr
```

are stored within `co_names` of a function object and not within `co_consts`:

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: def f():
   ...:     return numpy.array

In [4]: f.__code__.co_names
Out[4]: ('numpy', 'array')

In [5]: from dis import dis

In [7]: dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (numpy)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (array)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Is there any logic behind? I do not see any how global symbols used within a function are in any way similar to attribute names for specific objects. Since the attribute lookup is dynamic in Python it would me more logical IMO to store the attributes as string constants.

Related Question:

[Why does python VM have co_names instead of just using co_consts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28187661/why-does-python-vm-have-co-names-instead-of-just-using-co-consts)

Comment: "Since the attribute lookup is dynamic in Python" - so is global variable lookup.

Comment: I'm not sure how this question is different than the linked one. Why do you expect a different answer for attribute names than the answer given for global names in the other question? As you can see in your disassembly, they're both handled by special opcodes, and so it makes sense for both kinds of names to be stored the same way. If you really want the attribute name to be in `co_consts`, make your function call `getattr` with a constant string argument (e.g. `getattr(numpy, "array")`).

Comment: @user2357112 In case of global names one knows they should be in the globals. In case of attributes it is not known until the code is executed to which objects they correspond. I just do not see why the language designer(s) decided to keep such different things together.

Comment: @Blckknght Ok, so both global names and attributes are stored together because they are used differently than constants? I see some logic in it. On the other hand, `LOAD_ATTR` opcode could be designed to take attribute names from `co_const` and not from `co_names`.

Comment: "In case of global names one knows they should be in the globals" - not true. They could be in the built-ins. Anyway, it seems reasonable to me to store global names and attribute names together. They're both used when Python needs to look up a name in a namespace by string object. Sounds pretty similar to me.